# How Handbrake calculates width in "1080p30" preset

Tags: video, ffmpeg, resolution, video-conversion, handbrake

I have a video:

Resolution: `1920*1080`

PAR: `65536/65536`

**Rotation: `90°`**

In `Fast 1080p30` preset, The default value for Anamorphic option is `Automatic` and Modules `2`.

What I'm curious about is the **output** **width**. The height stays in `1080` as it should. But **how**/**why** the `width` changes to **1080** (`1080*1080`) and output video **is not stretched ?**

What is ffmpeg command or formula for calculating it?

---

[Download_Input - 9 MB](http://www.symphonyrecords.ir/input.mp4)

[Download_Output - 2 MB](http://www.symphonyrecords.ir/output.mp4)

**Input:**

```
General
Complete name               : C:\Users\PN\Desktop\input.mp4
Format                      : MPEG-4
Format profile              : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID                    : mp42 (isom/mp42)
File size                   : 9.82 MiB
Duration                    : 4 s 305 ms
Overall bit rate mode       : Variable
Overall bit rate            : 19.1 Mb/s
Encoded date                : UTC 2018-12-13 07:28:30
Tagged date                 : UTC 2018-12-13 07:28:30
com.android.version         : 7.0

Video
ID                          : 1
Format                      : AVC
Format/Info                 : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile              : Baseline@L4
Format settings             : 1 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC      : No
Format settings, ReFrames   : 1 frame
Format settings, GOP        : M=1, N=31
Codec ID                    : avc1
Codec ID/Info               : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                    : 4 s 305 ms
Source duration             : 4 s 314 ms
Bit rate mode               : Variable
Bit rate                    : 17.4 Mb/s
Maximum bit rate            : 17.0 Mb/s
Width                       : 1 920 pixels
Height                      : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio        : 16:9
Rotation                    : 90°
Frame rate mode             : Variable
Frame rate                  : 30.134 FPS
Minimum frame rate          : 24.311 FPS
Maximum frame rate          : 39.630 FPS
Original frame rate         : 30.000 FPS
Color space                 : YUV
Chroma subsampling          : 4:2:0
Bit depth                   : 8 bits
Scan type                   : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)          : 0.279
Stream size                 : 8.95 MiB (91%)
Source stream size          : 8.95 MiB (91%)
Title                       : VideoHandle
Language                    : English
Encoded date                : UTC 2018-12-13 07:28:30
Tagged date                 : UTC 2018-12-13 07:28:30
mdhd_Duration               : 4305

Audio
ID                          : 2
Format                      : AAC
Format/Info                 : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile              : LC
Codec ID                    : mp4a-40-2
Duration                    : 4 s 224 ms
Bit rate mode               : Constant
Bit rate                    : 192 kb/s
Channel(s)                  : 2 channels
Channel positions           : Front: L R
Sampling rate               : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                  : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode            : Lossy
Stream size                 : 99.3 KiB (1%)
Title                       : SoundHandle
Language                    : English
Encoded date                : UTC 2018-12-13 07:28:30
Tagged date                 : UTC 2018-12-13 07:28:30
```

**Output:**

```
General
Complete name               : C:\Users\PN\Desktop\output.mp4
Format                      : MPEG-4
Format profile              : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID                    : mp42 (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                   : 2.40 MiB
Duration                    : 4 s 334 ms
Overall bit rate mode       : Variable
Overall bit rate            : 4 640 kb/s
Encoded date                : UTC 2018-12-16 02:45:36
Tagged date                 : UTC 2018-12-16 02:45:36
Writing application         : HandBrake 1.1.2 2018090500

Video
ID                          : 1
Format                      : AVC
Format/Info                 : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile              : Main@L4
Format settings             : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC      : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames   : 4 frames
Codec ID                    : avc1
Codec ID/Info               : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                    : 4 s 334 ms
Bit rate                    : 4 467 kb/s
Width                       : 1 080 pixels
Height                      : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio        : 0.563
Frame rate mode             : Constant
Frame rate                  : 30.000 FPS
Color space                 : YUV
Chroma subsampling          : 4:2:0
Bit depth                   : 8 bits
Scan type                   : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)          : 0.128
Stream size                 : 2.31 MiB (96%)
Writing library             : x264 core 155 r2901 7d0ff22
Encoding settings           : cabac=1 / ref=2 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x1:0x111 / me=hex / subme=6 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=0 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=6 / lookahead_threads=1 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=1 / keyint=300 / keyint_min=30 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=30 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=22.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / vbv_maxrate=20000 / vbv_bufsize=25000 / crf_max=0.0 / nal_hrd=none / filler=0 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Encoded date                : UTC 2018-12-16 02:45:36
Tagged date                 : UTC 2018-12-16 02:45:36
Color range                 : Limited
Color primaries             : BT.709
Transfer characteristics    : BT.709
Matrix coefficients         : BT.709

Audio
ID                          : 2
Format                      : AAC
Format/Info                 : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile              : LC
Codec ID                    : mp4a-40-2
Duration                    : 4 s 246 ms
Bit rate mode               : Variable
Bit rate                    : 167 kb/s
Channel(s)                  : 2 channels
Channel positions           : Front: L R
Sampling rate               : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                  : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode            : Lossy
Stream size                 : 86.7 KiB (4%)
Title                       : Stereo / Stereo
Language                    : English
Default                     : Yes
Alternate group             : 1
Encoded date                : UTC 2018-12-16 02:45:36
Tagged date                 : UTC 2018-12-16 02:45:36
```

Comment: What does Handbrake have to do with ffmpeg? The question is unclear.

Comment: Handbrake uses ffmpeg under the hood.

Comment: To the OP, share the mediainfo readout for the input and output files.

Comment: @Gyan Sure. Added to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But how/why the width changes to 1080 (1080*1080)

The original video is 1920⨉1080, but it's actually rotated by 90° (portrait mode), so Handbrake rotates it back, which means that the height suddenly becomes 1920. For a 1080p preset, Handbrake will subsequently scale the image back to 1080 height.

> and output video is not stretched ?

Because Handbrake set the display aspect ratio (DAR) to 0.563, as visible in your output. This is what anamorphic scaling does.

> What is ffmpeg command or formula for calculating it?

1920⨉0.563 ~= 1080, so the horizontal value is "squeezed" to fit into 1080, then stretched while playing. You can also calculate the DAR as 9/16.

If you want to reproduce this kind of output with ffmpeg, you simply need to use the `scale` and `setdar` filters, e.g.

```
-vf scale=1080:1080,setdar=9:16
```

However, it is not clear from your question as to whether you really want or need this. I'd recommend just encoding the video with a DAR of 1. Optionally, you may want to rotate your videos back to landscape first, and reset the rotation flag with:

```
-metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0
```

Comment: Thank's for your response. I'm using ffmpeg to compress media in an android app. Curently I'm using this for **1080p preset**: `"-vf scale=-2:1080"`. Until I saw Handbrake is doing it in another way. I thought maybe I can do this better.

Comment: I check the height not being smaller than `1080`. if it is. then I use source height `"-vf scale=-2:srcHeight"`

Comment: No, what you are doing in Android is correct.

Comment: `-metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0` considering I'm using dynamic media source isn't it cleaner to let ffmpeg handle rotation by itself?

Comment: It depends on your use case. If you want to keep the rotation flag (e.g., if you know that your player supports it), then there's no need to reset it.